# How do you track the source of an error?

Tags: debugging, gdb, rust

For panics, `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` is very useful, but it doesn't do much for non-fatal errors.

For example, I have some code that ends with

```
match res {
    Ok(()) => (),
    Err(_) =>
        println_err!("{:?}", res),
}
```

Unfortunately, running in `gdb` doesn't do a whole lot by default, since nothing exceptional is happening. (Ye olde C++ behavior where unhandled exceptions would call `abort()` and `gdb` would break on `SIGABORT` by default was pretty convenient.)

Next, since `gdb` now supports reverse execution, I thought I could debug it by setting a breakpoint at the `println_err` line and reversing until I found the source of the error.

```
(gdb) reverse-step
Target multi-thread does not support this command.
```

A quick search revealed I should do something like

```
(gdb) set libthread-db-search-path /etc/nonexistent
(gdb) start
```

but then I get

```
(gdb) reverse-step
Target child does not support this command.
```

Does that mean reverse debugging just isn't supported in Rust? Or am I doing something wrong/suboptimal?

Is there a better solution than to manually go through each function that forwarded the error (with `try!()`) in order to find out where it originated?

Edit: Making use of manual breakpoints and restarting, I got to the point where the function was returning, but GDB can't seem to tell what the return value is:

```
(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  cafs::reader::Reader::read_rawblock (self=0x7fffffffd628, h=Sha256 = {...}) at src/reader.rs:90
0x00005555556a096b in cafs::reader::Reader::read_blockref_vec (self=0x7fffffffd628, r=Reader = {...}) at src/reader.rs:101
101             let raw = try!(self.read_rawblock(h));
Value returned is $3 = {union Result<collections::vec::Vec<u8>, std::io::error::Error> (struct Reader *, struct Sha256)} 0x0
(gdb)
```

So, maybe GDB will not be all that useful...

Answer (score 2):

Reverse debugging isn't as easy as `reverse-step`.  You have to stop at some point before the failure and ask gdb to `record`.  Then at some later point you can reverse.

The built-in record facility is on the slow side.  And, it doesn't support multi-threading.  It's difficult to recommend it beyond some smallish use cases.

If you're serious about pursuing reverse-debugging for this problem, let me recommend [rr-project](http://rr-project.org/).  It's a much better way to approach this.

Comment: Given GDB's apparent inability to understand Rust return values, I'm thinking that is no longer the way to go. I was trying reverse debugging because it worked really well when I used it in `ocamldebug`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have stacktraces with `Result<T, E>`, you can build a type that does that: http://phildawes.net/blog/2015/06/17/rust-stacktrace/

Comment: That would produce a trace to where the error first got converted in my code. It's certainly something, but I'd prefer to see where it originated in the library that produced it. It would be *really* nice if I could have `gdb` break there so I could examine state rather than just get a backtrace.

Comment: BTW, a similar alternative I had seen on Reddit is rust-throw. https://github.com/daboross/rust-throw/